# Factorization for special primes $P$, $Q$, and $R$

Tags: rsa, factoring

Suppose that $p$, $q$, and $r$ are distinct $n$-bit primes, we define
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
P & = & p \mathbin\Vert q \\
Q & = & q \mathbin\Vert r \\
R & = & r \mathbin\Vert p
\end{array}
$$
Where $\mathbin\Vert$ means concatenation of two integers. For example
$$1165993 \mathbin\Vert 1420831 = 11659931420831$$
We are given $N = P \times Q \times R$ and $P, Q, R \in \mathbb{P}$, that is they are primes too. Can we factor $N$ in polynomial time?
I have listed an example for this question too, we know that
$$\scriptsize N = P \times Q \times R = 12263640959607413166286548792372138857838409113471105337781351695720741222286495632687410855193016269011718576637693250596988228986909434347895553431945099$$

Can we factor it?

Comment: Could you tell us the origin of this question? What is the size of $p,q,r$?

Comment: Note $11659931420831 =  894167 \times 13039993$

Comment: @kelalaka $p, q, r$ are 85-bit primes, and I have constructed $P, Q, R$ from those three primes with concatenation that I defined above. Also these new integers are prime. Please note that $\mathbin\Vert$ just means concatenation, $5\mathbin\Vert7 = 57$, $1\mathbin\Vert1 = 11$, and etc.

Comment: $2^{2n}\cdot P + R - 2^n\cdot Q = (2^{3n}+1)\cdot p$, but I don't see how to use this in a lattice attack.

Comment: Are you using base 10 or base 2 concatenation here?

Comment: @SEJPM Base 10 concatenation

Comment: Again, what is the source?

Comment: @kelalaka A question for research for mine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that we currently know how to exploit such structure.

The set-up immediately makes one think of Coppersmith's method for factoring RSA moduli with some bits of the factors known. This constructs a two-variable integer polynomial with an unusually small integer solution and uses lattice methods to find the solution.

In this case the polynomial $(10^cX+Y)(10^cY+Z)(10^cZ+X)-N$ has the solution $(X,Y,Z)=(p,q,r)$ with $p,q,r\approx N^{1/6}$. However this is a polynomial in three variables which is [beyond our current knowledge of Coppersmith's method](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2007/45150361/45150361.pdf). The additional information that $p$, $q$ and $r$ are primes (and indeed that $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are primes) is not used by the methods, but I cannot see anyway to exploit this. If there are additional relationships between $p$, $q$ and $r$ that can eliminate on variable, more might be possible.

If you drop the polynomial-time requirement, then your example with $n=85$ can be solved in [four hours for less than $100](https://seclab.upenn.edu/projects/faas/).

Comment: There are papers using trivariate coppersmith for some funny attacks on RSA. Why care about "provable" variants?

Comment: @Fractalice The question asks about polynomial time, which I can only really make sense of in the abstract vice pragmatic sense. I'll confess to unfamiliarity with the full literature and there may be a version that does do precisely what is needed.

Comment: That is the use of fass here? I don't see that what is written here answers this question at all.  It is rather a comment. If you don't solve it why write as an answer instead of comment?